# Книги по глубочайшей архитектуре процессора

Tags: алгоритм, книги, процессор

Посоветуйте пожалуйста книги по архитектуре процессора (RISC, CISC, АЛУ и т.д.).
Я знаю, что это не по теме (хотя, это же Computer Science), но это не дает мне спокойно учить программирование. Везде написано "в общем", а я бы хотел разобрать это подробно.
Будьте людьми... Пожалуйста...
//В гуле написано просто:"Процессор выполняет  команду в пошагово:

Вызывает следующую команду из памяти и переносит её в регистр команд.
Меняет положение счётчика команд, который после этого указывает на следующую команду. Это происходит после декодирования текущей команды, в некоторых случаях в процессе.
Определяет тип вызванной команды.
Если команда использует слово из памяти, то определяет где оно находится.
Переносит слово в регистр центрального процессора. Некоторые команды загружают целые группы слов и обрабатывают их.
Выполняет команду
Переходит к 1 шагу, чтобы выполнять следующую команду.". И какая магия это все делает?

Comment: Заходите на сайт производителя процессора и скачиваете даташиты на процессор. Но там все на английском и объемы 500-1000-1500-2000 страниц и больше. Переводных материалов сейчас скорее всего нет.

Comment: Вряд ли понимание принципов работы процессора сыграет ключевую роль в осознании "общих" концепции современного программирования.

Comment: Интересно, как к именно процессору относятся такие тэги, как "windows" и "препроцессор"?... На этом фоне даже соглашусь с "алгоритмом" :), хотя даже "ассемблер" был бы ближе...

Comment: Ваш вопрос можно по аналогии перефразировать так: "...мне не дает спокойно осваивать летное мастерство и пилотирование незнание глубочайшей архитектуры самолета! Дайте же кто-нибудь мне полную документацию на этот самолет. Я не могу спокойно браться за штурвал, когда не знаю как устроен высотомер и гироскоп."

Comment: Человек к знаниям тянется, а вам бы только поязвить :) Автору - поясните, что вы понимаете под "глубочайшим", больно уж эпитет мощный. То, что в гугле находится по фразе "архитектура процессора лекции книги" - недостаточно глубоко?

Comment: Я понимаю вас. Сам такой. Тоже с трудом воспринимаю многие вещи, пока не пойму, как оно устроено "внутри". Для начала советую вернуться к школьным учебникам физики, почитать про электронно-дырочную проводимость, p-n переход и т. п. Воротит от учебников, погуглите статьи по этим темам. Также ищите, как устроены и работают диод, транзистор и другие элементы электронных схем. Далее идет триггер: комбинация транзисторов. Добавив к этому конденсатор (хранитель заряда) можно понять базовое устройство и работу электронных схем.

Comment: Недавно встречал рекомендации книги Digital Design and Computer Architecture (и версия ARM® Edition). Сам пока не читал, но вроде то, что нужно. Также я знаю, весьма популярна книга "Код. Тайный язык информатики" Чарльза Петцольда.

Comment: процессора без практики тяжело понять, лучше взять недорогую платку на чём-нибудь типа stm32 и попрограммировать

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Переходит к 1 шагу, чтобы выполнять следующую команду.". И какая магия
>   это все делает?

Это проще. Это вам нужно почитать что-нибудь из курса цифровой схемотехники. Как устроены триггеры, регистры, сумматоры-вычитатели, шифраторы-дешифраторы, генераторы-мультивибраторы. Далее как из этих элементов строят схемы шинной и не шинной топологии. Как из регистров строят ОЗУ. Такой литературы много есть и на русском. А институтская специальность цифровой схемотехники называется "Вычислительные машины сети и системы". Погуглите литературу по этой специальности и все узнаете.

Answer (score 2):

есть книги Таненнбаума "Архитектура компьютера","Современные операционные системы"